# I named a png image in lower case in android studio, but while running the project it shows error?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-activity, android-studio

I named a png image in lower case in android studio, but while running the project it shows error? I have added the screen shot also...[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: I can't see any error. can you put logcat text here

Comment: make category.png instead of category.PNG

Comment: extension must also be in lowercase

Answer (score 0):

Extension is UPPER_CASE change it to lower case and it will work with no problems